# Is it possible to use %edit in an IPython Notebook to edit in-browser?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have been using the magic %edit in Ipython to edit strings on the fly and was wondering whether this is also possible in an IPython Notebook without having to leave the browser (Possibly in a new cell)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `%edit` does not load variable content in a new cell in jupyter notebooks for now (https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/147).

However, you can load variable `s` contents in a new cell by using `%load s`. you can then edit the content and store it in a new variable from within the same cell.